# Poisson deviance - and what about zero observed values?

Tags: poisson-distribution, generalized-linear-model, deviance

According to Crawley *), the Poisson deviance is computed as

$2 \sum{O \cdot \log ({O \over E})}$

But what if observed value $O$ is zero?

*) *Statistical Computing - An Introduction to Data Analysis using S-Plus, Michael J. Crawley, printed by Wiley 2004, page 539.*

Comment: Since $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} x \log x = 0$, it is customary to extend the function $f(x) = x \log x$ to be defined on $[0,\infty)$ and set $f(0) = 0$. Hence, the deviance would be zero.

Comment: By the way, can you give an exact citation from which you're drawing your question? That looks like a *binomial* deviance to me and not a *Poisson* deviance. (The latter has an additional term.)

Comment: @cardinal, it's a book: *Statistical Computing - An Introduction to Data Analysis using S-Plus, Michael J. Crawley, printed by Wiley 2004, page 539.* I have also seen a different definition elsewhere, which is similar but also includes a term $-(O-E)$.

Comment: @cardinal, anyway, this means that for observed zeros the deviance is not increased? That means that zero-inflated data would not increase deviance, which is odd. So is this the reason why probably this definition isn't correct?

Comment: @cardinal ((& Tomas) The additional term in $\sum(O-E)$ is zero when fitting a standard Poisson log-linear regression model by maximum likelihood if the model includes a constant (intercept) term. Crawley has specified a log-linear model on [the previous page](http://books.google.com/books?id=OlPUa6lVeb0C&pg=PA538). I can't immediately spot anything about including a constant term, but S-Plus (and all other software i know) would include one unless you specifically asked it not to.

Comment: Tomas, consider a zero-inflated model in which an extra probability of $\delta$ is assigned to $0$.  To balance this, all other expectations have to be divided by $1-\delta$.  This changes the deviance expression by $2\sum O \cdot \log(1-\delta)$ (the sum is over nonzero values).  Thus the deviance *will* change when inflating the zero term.

Comment: @onestop: Thanks. I don't have immediate access to that text, so it helps to have the full context that you've provided. That makes it clear why the second term vanishes here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Cardinals' comment:

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \ x \log x = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \log x}{1 \over x} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 \over x}{-1 \over x^2} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} -x = 0$